# is.atomic() vs is.vector()

Tags: r, vector, data-structures, atomic, typeof

I don't understand the difference between `is.atomic()` and `is.vector()`. From my understanding, `is.vector()` returns `TRUE` for homogeneous 1D data structures. I believe `is.atomic()` returns `TRUE` for logicals, doubles, integers, characters, complexes, and raws...however, wouldn't `is.vector()` as well? So I thought perhaps the difference lies in its dimensions, but `is.atomic()` returned `FALSE` on a dataframe of doubles, which made me even more confused, ah...

Also, what is the difference between an atomic vector and a normal vector?

Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Atomic vectors are a subset of vectors in R. In the general sense, a "vector" can be an atomic vector, a list or an expression. The [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects) sort of defines vectors as "contiguous cells containing data". Also refer to `help("is.vector")` and `help("is.atomic")`, which explain when these return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
is.vector(list())
#[1] TRUE
is.vector(expression())
#[1] TRUE
is.vector(numeric())
#[1] TRUE

is.atomic(list())
#[1] FALSE
is.atomic(expression())
#[1] FALSE
is.atomic(numeric())
#[1] TRUE
```

Colloquially, we usually mean atomic vectors (possibly even with attributes) when we talk about vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors in R can have 2 structures, the first one, atomic vectors, and the second one, lists.

If you create a new, empty vector, you can specify the mode to get an empty list `vector(mode = "list")` which returns the same as `list()`.

```
identical(vector(mode = "list"), list())
[1] TRUE
```

`is.vector(vector(mode = "list"))` returns `[1] TRUE`,  whereas is.atomic(vector(mode = "list")) returns `[1] FALSE`.